# apim named values for xml param bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-bicep

I am working on Azure APIM bicep deployment and most of things are working . Now I am working on parameterizing the xml policy file.
How can I parameterized using name values?

I tried following two example but its not working.

E.g. I set value in xml file `{{ratelimit-value}}` and created named value in apim with same name. So my xml policy looks like below

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <rate-limit calls="{{ratelimit-value}}" renewal-period="60" />
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

When I deploy it as it I am getting error in GitHub action as below

```
ERROR: ***"status":"Failed","error":***"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[***"code":"Conflict","message":"***\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": ***\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      ***\r\n        \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed\",\r\n        \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.\",\r\n        \"details\": [\r\n          ***\r\n            \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n            \"message\": \"***\\r\\n  \\\"error\\\": ***\\r\\n    \\\"code\\\": \\\"ValidationError\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"message\\\": \\\"One or more fields contain incorrect values:\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"details\\\": [\\r\\n      ***\\r\\n        \\\"code\\\": \\\"ValidationError\\\",\\r\\n        \\\"target\\\": \\\"rate-limit\\\",\\r\\n        \\\"message\\\": \\\"Error in element 'rate-limit' on line 3, column 10: Cannot find a property 'ratelimit-value'\\\"\\r\\n      ***\\r\\n    ]\\r\\n  ***\\r\\n***\"\r\n          ***\r\n        ]\r\n      ***\r\n    ]\r\n  ***\r\n***"***]***
```

policy reference in bicep file

// policy for all api resources

```
resource apiPolicy 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/policies@2021-08-01' = {
  name: 'policy'
  parent: api
  properties: {
    format: 'rawxml'
    value: loadTextContent('./policies/all_operations_policy.xml')
  }
}
```

How can I used named value created in APIm and reference in xml file dring bicep deployment

Comment: Please make sure Named Values - `ratelimit-value` is *already* created in the deployment environment before you deploy the APIM policy. Are you getting the error when it is already there?

Comment: can you please provide  more details on "created in deployment environment" . I am using Github action and this named value is already created in apim

Comment: Yeah you would need to have the `ratelimit-value` created before deploying the policy. If it s define in the same template, you would need a dependsOn or implicte dependency

Comment: would you be able to share part of your bicep files ?

Comment: @Thomas , I am simply loading the policy , i have updated my question to add that reference. If you have any example where Named values already created in APIM and in bicep file simply using it in XML that would be great .